# Add a space if a letter is adjacent to a number

Tags: excel, vba

I´m trying to unify the format of a large .xlsx file I received.

One of the problems I found, is that there are entries which "unique code" is "00UTract 32", "132Unit 359", "5555UT22"... and then I´ve found we´ve "00 UTract 32", "Unit 359, 132", and "22UT, 5555".

As you may suspect, there are duplicates, and I confirmed that was the case.

So, how should I do to add a space each time I find a letter next to a number, so I can start cleaning the mess easily?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells you wish to check/correct and run this macro:

```
Sub DataFixer()
    Dim r As Range, DoIt As Boolean
    Dim temp As String, CH As String, v As String
    Dim i As Long, L As Long
    For Each r In Selection
        temp = ""
        DoIt = False
        v = r.Value
        L = Len(v)
        CH = Mid(v, 1, 1)
        temp = CH
        For i = 2 To L
            CH = Mid(v, i, 1)
            If IsNumeric(Right(temp, 1)) And CH Like "[a-zA-Z]" Then
                DoIt = True
                temp = temp & " "
            End If
            temp = temp & CH
        Next i
        If DoIt Then r.Value = temp
    Next r
End Sub
```

The macro checks each select cell for occurrences of:

```
{number}{letter}
```

and replaces them with:

```
{number} {letter}
```

Comment: Thanks Gary´s Student! Could you please add some comments or briefly explain me how it works?

Comment: @user3849732 the macro examines cell-by-cell.  Within each cell, the characters are examined.  If the program detects a *letter,* it check the previous character.  If the previous character was a *number,* a single space is placed between them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do this the other way around **assuming that the only difference in IDs are the spaces.**
Simply **remove** all **spaces** from that column, and you will get the same values, without having to deal with checking each character in a string.

This can be done via CTRL+H and no need to introduce VB in it.

Comment: Alex, I did try that but didn´t work because there´s no respected order in the codes. 
As in "5555UT22", which is then "22UT, 5555", if I assume that I would still have a different coding. 
I want to separate each, so I can apply some other matching algorithms that would work better as It will be easier to recognize that - supposing I can do what I´m asking - "5555 UT 22" is the same as "22 UT, 5555" than matching "5555UT22" with "22UT, 5555".